# The follow curve option in follow path constrain squeezes the mesh

Tags: constraints

I am trying to animate a fighter jet to follow along a path. but as soon as I turn on the follow curve option in follow path constraint, it squeezes the mesh. please help me in this matter.[image: Contraint 1]

[image: Mesh 1]

[image: Contraint 2]

[image: Mesh 2]

Comment: Have you checked that the scale is applied for both objects?  you might consider editing your post to  [share](https://blend-exchange.com/) your .blend file.

Comment: Thank You. Applying the scale for the path did the job.